# What is the best way to create a rules engine to handle "And/Or" logic

Tags: .net, sql, bit-manipulation

for example...

```
if( (stuCourses.contains("crs101") && stuCourses.contains("crs102") && 
    stuCourses.contains("crs103"))  || (stuCourses.contains("crs201") && 
    stuCourses.contains("crs202")) || stuCourses.contains("crs300") )
{
    //then student can register for crs301;
}
```

Also, what's the best table schemas for something like this i.e. courses/coursePrerequisites...how would you structure the table fields to handle "and/or" logic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. If that's really the logic you need, I'm not sure I see a problem with doing it the way you have it. If your app is data-driven, you could run comparisons against the data, but the logic would not be trivial.

Comment: No, the example I wrote is unacceptable. Think about how unruly that would get over time. What if I needed the same logic in some other system. What if one of courses changed.

Comment: This feels like two different halves of two different questions. How are your .net logic and SQL table questions related? Maybe revise your question to give us a bigger-picture/better idea about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I reworded the question. Hopefully that clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the following tables. It's a bit complex so if this is a small implementation, just updating the code as above might be easier!

```
Courses(ID, Name, ...)
-- Information about each course

CoursePrerequisiteRules(ID, CourseID, PrerequisiteRuleID, ValidFrom, ValidTo)
-- Assigns a single rule to a particular course, for a particular range of academic years

PrerequisiteRules(ID, RuleType)
-- The header record defining a rule or sub-rule for a specific course

PrerequisiteRuleCourseMembers(ID, PrerequisiteCourseID, PrequisiteRuleID)
-- Each record assigns one course to a prerequisite rule.

PrerequisiteRuleRuleMembers(ID, ParentPrerequisiteRuleID, ChildPrerequisiteRuleID)
-- Each record assigns one prerequisite rule as a child of another rule
```

PrerequisiteRules.RuleType would be 'AND' or 'OR'. A prerequisite rule can have courses assigned to it using PrerequisiteRuleCourseMembers or other rules assigned to it using PrerequisiteRuleRuleMembers. Each course would have one rule active at a time, but these  could be defined on a per academic year basis if needed (using ValidFrom and ValidTo of CoursePrequisiteRules). Complex trees of rules can be created as sub-rules of this one rule.

e.g. to state the requirement that CS320 needs (CS101 OR CS102) AND MT101:

```
Courses
ID  Name
1   CS101
2   CS102
3   MT101
4   CS320

CoursePrerequisites
ID  CourseID PrerequisiteRuleID  ValidFrom  ValidTo
5   4        7                   2010       2012
-- The rule for CS320 between 2010 and 2012 is rule number 7

PrerequisiteRules
ID  RuleType
6   "OR"
7   "AND"
-- Rule number 7 performs an AND on all its children
-- Rule number 6 uses an OR instead

PrerequisiteRuleCourseMembers
ID  PrerequisiteCourseID   PrequisiteRuleID
8   1                      6
9   2                      6
10  3                      7
-- This assigns CS101 and CS102 to rule 6, meaning that rule 6 should be evaluated as
-- CS101 OR CS102. It also assigns MT101 to rule 7.

PrerequisiteRuleRuleMembers
ID  ParentPrerequisiteRuleID ChildPrerequisiteRuleID
11  7                        6
-- This assigns Rule 6 to Rule 7, so with the row in the previous table, rule 7 becomes
-- MT101 AND [Rule 6]
-- ...which means MT101 AND (CS101 OR CS102)
```

Comment: Appreciate all the feedback but I think this is the best structure solution so far. However, following your idea, I would change the table structure to the following:                

- Courses  
- Prerequisite Rules  
- Prerequisites (store all courses that belong to a prerequisite)  
- Prerequisite Sets (break course prerequisites into sets - all sets must have a unique prerequisite rule)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think it's the conditional itself that needs to change... Just the level of abstraction represented by it.  This does seem messy:

```
if((stuCourses.contains("crs101") && stuCourses.contains("crs102") && stuCourses.contains("crs103")) || (stuCourses.contains("crs201") && stuCourses.contains("crs202")) || stuCourses.contains("crs300") )
{
    //then student can register for crs301;
}
```

But not for the reasons you think.  The and/or logic can be formatted to look nicer, but more importantly it should be abstracted into another function.  Something like this:

```
public void RegisterStudentForCRS301()
{
    // other stuff
    if (StudentHasTakenNecessaryCourses())
    {
        // etc.
    }
}

private bool StudentHasTakenNecessaryCourses()
{
    return
        StudentHasTakenNecessary100LevelCourses() ||
        StudentHasTakenNecessary200LevelCourses() ||
        StudentHasTakenNecessary300LevelCourses()
    ;
}

private bool StudentHasTakenNecessary100LevelCourses()
{
    return
        stuCourses.contains("crs101") &&
        stuCourses.contains("crs102") &&
        stuCourses.contains("crs103")
    ;
}

private bool StudentHasTakenNecessary200LevelCourses()
{
    return
        stuCourses.contains("crs201") &&
        stuCourses.contains("crs202")
    ;
}

private bool StudentHasTakenNecessary300LevelCourses()
{
    return
        stuCourses.contains("crs300")
    ;
}
```

Each function has its own level of abstraction and is responsible for one thing and only one thing.  The functions aggregate into higher-level functions which check the logic across multiple levels of abstraction.  And it all aggregates up into the public functionality, which doesn't care about the details it just needs to know the business concept (is the student eligible?).

Each level of abstraction is easy to read and understand.  Heck, you don't even need to be a programmer to read the logic, once one has a basic explanation of what `&&` and `||` mean.  Sure, it's a lot more code.  But it's expressive code that *very clearly* describes in no uncertain terms what it's doing.  If one isn't interested in the details of the logic and just needs to know the high-level business functionality, one doesn't even need to look at the comparison logic.  Just call the appropriately-named function.  Let the lower levels of abstraction handle the lower details.

Comment: The example I provided was just that...an example so you could visualize what I was talking about...not actual code. Writing a new function for each course series is just not an option.

Comment: @JoeWeb: Then perhaps the example wasn't clear.  Was the question about how to write clear conditional logic, or about how to create a rules engine for a course pre-requisite system?  It sounded like the former, but now you're implying the latter.

Comment: Creating database tables and a rules engine to handle "And/Or" logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would come up with a simple language for describing course requirements and specify each course's requirements in that language. Then write a very simple engine that takes a course requirement description and checks if a student's course set meets it.

You could use a simple list of course combinations using `&` to separate courses within a combination and `|` to separate combinations, like this:

```
crs101&crs102&crs103|crs201&crs202|crs300
```

You would then store that in the database as the "prerequisites" for crs301.

The engine would then loop over the string separating it at the `|` marks. It would then separate each entry in turn at the `&` marks, skipping to the next if a course isn't matched.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be easier to do it in XML and store the XML in the database.

Comment: @Jim: That certainly works too. I don't have any strong feelings about the format. Basically, you should use whatever you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest that the best way to accomplish this is by storing your "prerequisite rules" in XML, either in the database or in a hard file depending on your application architecture and needs.  XML is well suited to your needs because you can store prerequisite sets, like...

```
<Courses>
    <Course>
        <CourseCode>crs301</CourseCode>
        <PrereqSets>
            <PrereqSet>
                <CourseCode>crs101<CourseCode>
                <CourseCode>crs102<CourseCode>
                <CourseCode>crs103<CourseCode>
            </PrereqSet>
            <PrereqSet>
                <CourseCode>crs201<CourseCode>
                <CourseCode>crs202<CourseCode>
            </PrereqSet>
            <PrereqSet>
                <CourseCode>crs300<CourseCode>
            </PrereqSet>
        </PrereqSets>
    </Course>
    <Course> 
    <!--Some other course data goes here-->
    </Course>
</Courses>
```

You can then use XPath to query out of the XML data quite easily.

There are of course other ways to accomplish this by just storing the data in a database.  One such way might be to store it in an associative table with a composite key, such as below...

```
Course table
    CourseID, Name
    1, crs101
    2, crs102
    3, crs103
    4, crs201
    5, crs202
    6, crs300
    7, crs301


CoursePrereqMap table
    CourseID, PrereqSetID, PrereqCourseID
    7, 1, 1
    7, 1, 2
    7, 1, 3
    7, 2, 4
    7, 2, 5
    7, 3, 6
```

Any way you do it, you can then load the Prerequisite Sets either into custom objects (i.e. VOs or DTOs if those aren't outdated terms), or into some kind of lists or arrays and write a method that will process an entire Prerequisite set, or maybe even a list or array of Prerequisite Sets, and ensure all courses at least one set are completed.

I hope this answers your second question about how to store such data.  This is not a concrete answer so much as a suggestion on a few ways you could go about implementing it; there's of course a ton of approaches you could take.